# Example of two different contact forms with the same Reeb vector field and exterior derivative.

Tags: tensors, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry, contact-geometry

Consider $\mathbb{R}^3$ (or more generally $\mathbb{R}^{2n-1}$), are there two different contact forms $\alpha_1 \neq \alpha_2$ with the same Reeb vector field and exterior derivative i.e. $d\alpha_1=d\alpha_2$?

Equivalently, does Reeb vector field and $d\alpha$ determine $\alpha$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this data doesn't determine $\alpha$. Here's a counterexample.

On $\mathbb R^3$, consider
\begin{align*}
\alpha_1 &= x\,dy + dz,\\
\alpha_2 &= x\,dy + dz + dx.
\end{align*}
Then $d\alpha_1 = d\alpha_2 = dx\wedge dy$, and both Reeb fields are equal to $\partial/\partial z$.

More generally, if $\alpha_1$ is any contact form whatsoever and $T_1$ is its Reeb field, we can take $\alpha_2 = \alpha_1 + du$, where $u$ is any smooth function such that $T_1(u) \equiv 0$.

(It's always possible to find a nontrivial such example locally. Whether it can be done globally is a more subtle question that I don't know a general answer to. For example, if $T_1$ has a dense orbit, then every solution to $T_1(u)=0$ is constant.)

Comment: Thank you for your exhaustive answer. Does this mean that two such a forms will always differ exactly by an exact form which vanishes on $T_1$?

Comment: Two such forms will always differ by a closed $1$-form $\eta$ that satisfies $\eta(T_1)\equiv 0$. On $\mathbb R^{2n-1}$ (or any space with trivial first de Rham cohomology), this form will always be exact.

Comment: So what would be example of contact manifold where two such forms do not differ by an exact form?